# Magento Reindex Price error

Tags: magento, product, reindex

I have an issue on reindexing product prices
I was able to catch this

string(727) "INSERT INTO `catalog_product_index_group_price` SELECT `gp`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id`, MIN(IF(gp.website_id = 0, ROUND(gp.value * cwd.rate, 4), gp.value)) FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price` AS `gp` INNER JOIN `customer_group` AS `cg` ON gp.all_groups = 1 OR (gp.all_groups = 0 AND gp.customer_group_id = cg.customer_group_id) INNER JOIN `core_website` AS `cw` ON gp.website_id = 0 OR gp.website_id = cw.website_id INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_website` AS `cwd` ON cw.website_id = cwd.website_id WHERE (cw.website_id != 0) GROUP BY `gp`.`entity_id`, `cg`.`customer_group_id`, `cw`.`website_id` ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `price` = VALUES(`price`), `value_type` = VALUES(`value_type`)"

In  catalog_product_index_group_price there are standard 4 columns, but now I have 5
5   value_type  varchar(48) utf8_general_ci     No  fixed

I do not know where it appeared from or what generates it. I have tested all modules on a new Magento installation and all is ok. No module upgrades database.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the LOCKS directory from the 
    var/ folder 
Remove the cache directory in the 
    var/ folder

If you still are having a problem you can truncate your index tables for price
Some examples are : (**You can view your index tables and add or remove**)

- truncate catalog_product_index_price_bundle_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_bundle_opt_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_bundle_sel_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_agr_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_cfg_opt_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_downlod_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_final_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_opt_agr_idx;
- truncate catalog_product_index_price_opt_idx;

Comment: Sorry but nothing helped me. I have cleared all var folder before posting here. I have installed a new magento store with all extensions but the column value_type in catalog_product_index_group_price is not present. OK. I can delete that but the SQL still transmits it as a component of sql command line. So the question is who is sending that variable to ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post because I was facing a reindex of 'catalog_product_price' too. I've fixed it by doing:

**1. Enable db logging**

edit `lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php`

change `protected $_debug` to `true;`

**2. Reindex the corrupted index again and pull the whole SQL query + error from var/debug/pdo_mysql.log**

You'll see probably something like this

> EXCEPTION  exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`db`.`catalog_product_index_group_price`, CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_M_CAT_PRD_IDX_GROUP_PRICE_ENTT_ID_M_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` )' in
>   /www/sites/example.com/files/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

**3. Get more information about the failing constraint by looking at the table structure:**

run     `show create table catalog_product_index_group_price;`

You'll see probably something like this

> CONSTRAINT
>   `FK_M_CAT_PRD_IDX_GROUP_PRICE_ENTT_ID_M_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`entity_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`)
>   ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,

**4. Find out which entity_id is missing in the catalog_product_entity table**

run `SELECT cpigp.* FROM catalog_product_entity_group_price cpigp LEFT JOIN catalog_product_entity p ON cpigp.entity_id = p.entity_id WHERE ISNULL(p.entity_id);`

**5. Backup the corrupted table and delete the missing product**

run `DELETE FROM catalog_product_entity_group_price WHERE entity_id=XXXXX;`

**6. Reindex**